# Upgrade CentOS 7.9 to 8.5 incomplete - suggestions to fix?

Tags: centos, upgrade

I have a CentOS 7.9 server mostly running ZFS as a Windows CIFs file server and NFS vmware share. It was running v7 fine.  I tried leapp/elevate to migrate but it failed because of NFS so I tried upgrading to v8 to see if I could then jump to Alma.

I followed the steps from https://techglimpse.com/how-to-upgrade-centos-7-to-centos-8-linux/ and this command failed:

```
dnf -y --releasever=8 --allowerasing --setopt=deltarpm=false distro-sync
```

with a bunch of dependency errors.

**But**

- `cat /etc/redhat-release` shows `CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111`.
- the kernel is still `3.10.0-1160.90.1.el7.x86_64`

Running `dnf update` says it will install 98 packages, update 746 packages, and skip 255. But it fails with:

```
Running transaction check

Transaction check succeeded.

Running transaction test

The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.

You can remove cached packages by executing `dnf clean packages`.

Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libgdbm_compat.so.4.0.0 from install of gdbm-libs-1:1.18-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/ibdev2netdev from install of rdma-core-35.0-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ibutils-1.5.7-14.el7.x86_64
  file /etc/httpd/conf.d/README from install of httpd-filesystem-2.4.37-43.module_el8.5.0+1022+b541f3b1.noarch conflicts with file from package httpd-2.4.6-99.el7.centos.1.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/targetctl from install of target-restore-2.1.74-1.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python-rtslib-2.1.74-1.el7_9.noarch
  file /usr/bin/pflags from install of python3-linux-procfs-0.6.3-1.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python-linux-procfs-0.4.11-4.el7.noarch
  file /usr/bin/chardetect from install of python3-chardet-3.0.4-7.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python-chardet-2.2.1-3.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/__pycache__/six.cpython-36.opt-1.pyc from install of platform-python-setuptools-39.2.0-6.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/__pycache__/six.cpython-36.opt-1.pyc from install of platform-python-setuptools-39.2.0-6.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/__pycache__/six.cpython-36.pyc from install of platform-python-setuptools-39.2.0-6.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/__pycache__/six.cpython-36.pyc from install of platform-python-setuptools-39.2.0-6.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.2.0.dist-info/METADATA from install of platform-python-setuptools-39.2.0-6.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.2.0.dist-info/RECORD from install of platform-python-setuptools-39.2.0-6.el8.noarch conflicts with file from package python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch
```

and a lot more.

The command `` rpm -e `rpm -q kernel` ``  shows:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        kernel >= 3.10.0-384.el7 is needed by (installed) hypervfcopyd-0-0.34.20180415git.el7.x86_64
        kernel >= 3.10.0-384.el7 is needed by (installed) hypervvssd-0-0.34.20180415git.el7.x86_64
        kernel >= 2.6.32 is needed by (installed) lldpad-1.0.1-7.git036e314.el7_9.x86_64
        kernel >= 3.10.0-1133.el7 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel >= 3.10.0-384.el7 is needed by (installed) hypervkvpd-0-0.34.20180415git.el7.x86_64
        kernel(PDE_DATA) = 0x44f0d59d is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(___ratelimit) = 0x155f4108 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__bitmap_weight) = 0x4cbbd171 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__cond_resched_lock) = 0xe2cfb038 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__fentry__) = 0xbdfb6dbb is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__init_waitqueue_head) = 0xf432dd3d is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__kmalloc) = 0xd2b09ce5 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__list_add) = 0x0343a1a8 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__list_del_entry) = 0x65e75cb6 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__mutex_init) = 0x9a025cd5 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__stack_chk_fail) = 0xf0fdf6cb is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__vmalloc) = 0xa9bd2676 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__wake_up) = 0xcf21d241 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r10) = 0x7e526bfa is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r12) = 0x263ed23b is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r13) = 0xe7b00dfb is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r14) = 0xce8b1878 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r15) = 0x0f05c7b8 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r8) = 0x1ed8b599 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_r9) = 0xdf566a59 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rax) = 0x2ea2c95c is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rbx) = 0x593c1bac is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rcx) = 0xc29957c3 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rdx) = 0xb601be4c is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(__x86_indirect_thunk_rsi) = 0xa1f9a134 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(_cond_resched) = 0xa1c76e0a is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(_raw_qspin_lock) = 0x4b7dcf38 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(_raw_qspin_lock_irq) = 0x3588d8ba is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(_raw_read_lock) = 0x9b0c8220 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(_raw_spin_lock_bh) = 0x1637ff0f is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(_raw_spin_lock_irqsave) = 0x9327f5ce is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(_raw_spin_unlock_bh) = 0xba63339c is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore) = 0x08f64aa4 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(_raw_write_lock) = 0x13a1a61a is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(autoremove_wake_function) = 0xc8b57c27 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(bdevname) = 0x8f619a88 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(bio_add_page) = 0x4554b079 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(bio_alloc_bioset) = 0xeb862489 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(bio_endio) = 0xdd5fbc2b is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(bio_put) = 0x867c68af is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(bio_reset) = 0x060f6a84 is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
        kernel(bioset_create) = 0x1b57183e is needed by (installed) kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.23-5.el7.x86_64
```

and many more.

Is there a path to resolve the issues?

Comment: I was reading the comments in this article https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-centos-7-to-centos-8/comment-page-11/#comments.  It has a few tips I will try and let you know.  But will need to wait for the weekend or later.

Answer (score 0):

> suggestions to fix...

CentOS, few years back, transitioned to ***CentOS Stream***, and version 8 ***stream*** end of life is stated at 5/31/2024, less than a year away!

**Rocky Linux** is what CentOS used to be before *stream*, and it's v8 EOL is 5/31/2029.

While their download page doesn't state 8.x version number, the current download is `Rocky-8.8-x86_64-dvd1.iso`, which is 11.7gb and is what you'd want to go with if you don't want version 9.

https://rockylinux.org/download

migrate your data, reformat your OS disk(s), clean install `Rocky-8.8-x86_64-dvd1.iso`, move your data back, install stuff that you need.